# I can't upload my shinyapp on shinyapp.io (an error has occured - the application failed to start - exit status 1)

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to upload my shinyapp to shinyapp.io serve but every time it deployes it gives me this error:

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start.
exit status 1
```

This error appear on my google chrome screen, and on my shinyapp serve dashboard, it shows me that the app is running normally. However, when you open it, it just gives me a white screen with this error:

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start.
exit status 1
```

Here is my code:

```
data <- read.csv("new.csv")
baseline_table <- read.csv("baseline.csv")
operative_table <- read.csv("operative_details.csv")
postoptable1 <- read.csv("postop1.csv")
postoptable2 <- read.csv("postop2.csv")
outcomes <- read.csv("outcomes.csv")

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Efficacy and Safety of Carotid Endarterctomy",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Baseline summary",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("risk_factors_input", "Baseline data - Risk factors", 
                    c("HTN", "DM", "Coronary.artery.disease", "Peripheral.artery.disease", "Symptoms_Dysartheria", "CHF", "Malignancy")),
        selectInput("symptoms_input", "Baseline data - Symptoms at presentation", 
                    c("Symptoms.of.facial.weakness", "Symptoms_Amourosis.fugax", "Symptoms_Dysartheria", "Symptoms_hemiparesis", "Symptoms_ataxia", "monoparesis", "amnesia", "other"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
          column(6, plotOutput("risk_factors")),
          column(6, plotOutput("symptoms"))
        ),
        tableOutput("baselinetab")
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Operative details",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("action_operative", "Analyze Operated side")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("operativetable"),
        plotOutput("action_plot_operative")
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Postoperative details",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("action_postoperative", "Show postoperative complications")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("postop"),
        fluidRow(
          column(6, tableOutput("postoptable1")),
          column(6, tableOutput("postoptable2"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Outcomes",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("action", "Analyze Complications")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("mainoutcomes"),
        plotOutput("details_outcomes"),
        tableOutput("outcomes_table")
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Factors predicting complications",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("factors_predict_comp", "Choose a factor to predict complications", 
                    c("HTN", "DM", "Coronary.artery.disease", "Peripheral.artery.disease", "Symptoms_Dysartheria"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("reg_output")
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Factors predicting restenosis",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("factors_predict_restenosis", "Choose a factor to predict restenosis", 
                    c("HTN", "DM", "Coronary.artery.disease", "Peripheral.artery.disease", "Symptoms_Dysartheria"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("reg_output2")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$risk_factors <- renderPlot({
    data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = .data[[input$risk_factors_input]]))  +
      geom_bar(width = .4, fill = "#80b3d1", color = "black") + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=9))
  })
  
  output$symptoms <- renderPlot({
    data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = .data[[input$symptoms_input]]))  +
      geom_bar(width = .4, fill = "#80b3d1", color = "black") + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=9))
  })
  
  output$baselinetab <- renderTable({
    baseline_table 
    
  })
  
  
  output$postoptable1 <- renderTable({
    postoptable1
    
  })
  
  output$postoptable2 <- renderTable({
    postoptable2
    
  })
  
  
action_postpop <- eventReactive(input$action_postoperative, {
    data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x= Follow.up)) +
      geom_bar(width = .4,  fill = "#80b3d1", color = "black")+  
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=9),
            legend.text=element_text(size=12)) 
  })
  
  output$postop <- renderPlot({
    action_postpop()
  })
  
  output$mainoutcomes <- renderPlot({
    data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x= Complications_new))  +
      geom_bar(width = .4, fill = "#80b3d1", color = "black") + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=9))
  })
  
  
  action_plot_operative_function <- eventReactive(input$action_operative, {
    data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Operated.Side))  +
      geom_bar(width = .4, fill = "#80b3d1", color = "black") + 
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=9))
  })
  
  output$action_plot_operative <- renderPlot({
    action_plot_operative_function()
  })
  
  output$operativetable <- renderTable({
    operative_table
    
  })
  
  action_plot <- eventReactive(input$action, {
    data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x= Complications_new, fill = Complications)) +
      geom_bar(width = .4,  color = "black")+  
      theme_bw() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=9),
            legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
      xlab("Complication details")
  })
  
  output$details_outcomes <- renderPlot({
    action_plot()
  })
  
  output$outcomes_table <- renderTable({
    outcomes
  })
  
  output$reg_output <- renderTable({
    logisticR <- glm(as.factor(Complications_new) ~ eval(parse(text = input$factors_predict_comp)), data, family = binomial())
    reg_table <- Publish::publish(logisticR)
    reg_table$regressionTable <- as.data.frame(reg_table$regressionTable)
    variable <- input$factors_predict_comp
    reg_table$regressionTable[reg_table$regressionTable == "eval(parse(text = input$factors_predict_comp))",1] <- variable 
    reg_table$regressionTable
  })
  
  output$reg_output2 <- renderTable({
    logisticRS <- glm(as.factor(Restenosis) ~ eval(parse(text = input$factors_predict_restenosis)), data, family = binomial())
    reg_tableS <- Publish::publish(logisticRS)
    reg_tableS$regressionTable <- as.data.frame(reg_tableS$regressionTable)
    variableS <- input$factors_predict_restenosis
    reg_tableS$regressionTable[reg_tableS$regressionTable == "eval(parse(text = input$factors_predict_restenosis))",1] <- variableS 
    reg_tableS$regressionTable
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)

names(data)
```

I tried removing lines like (library (shiny) ) but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All your needed library calls have to be in the app.R file. The ‘packrat’ or ‘renv’ packages regex the `library`/ /`require`/`::` calls and build the dependency structure with will be installed on the target server.

Please add at the top of the file calls for all dependencies

```r
library(shiny) 
library(ggplot2)
library(Publish)
...
```

Another thing please check if during deployment you attached all needed CSV files.

Please refer to https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/Troubleshooting.html for more information